# nginx / symfony route to public/styles folder not working

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

this my first time I configure nginx for a symfony project(using docker).

Everything was well for the route to my index file. 
But now I need to use the route to public/styles/*****.css and other like public/js, etc.

I cannot get this running. It always tells me the route is not allowed from symfony or in other tries from nginx not allowed, HTML500.

This is my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
 server_name ~.*;

 location / {
     root /usr/src/app;
     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
 }

 location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
     client_max_body_size 50m;

     fastcgi_pass php:9000;
     fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
     fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/src/app/symfony/public/index.php;
 }

 error_log /dev/stderr debug;
 access_log /dev/stdout;
}
```

This is what I try to call:

```
http://localhost:8000/styles/main.css
http://localhost:8000 -> works proper, loading my index route
```

This is the part of my base.html.twig

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: do you run Nginx and Symfony in the same docker image?

Comment: No, nginx and php are running in separate containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If files is located on /usr/src/app/public/styles/ , then change your root directive value

http://localhost:8000/styles/main.css takes files from "{root}/styles/main.css" according to [nginx root directive doc](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root), and your "{root}/styles/main.css" is "/usr/src/app/styles/" now.

**UPDATE:**

If the backend can translates /style to /public/styles then you need proxy requests to backend (see [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) or search snippets for proxying), else you need move index.php to public and change root, else move /public/styles to /styles in your local file system.

Proxying get more sense since you said that you used separated docker containers for the backend. (It can be done by [linking containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#connect-with-the-linking-system) and proxying by `proxypass http://other-docker-container-name:XXXX`, where `XXXX` is exposed port on the other container)

**UPDATE 2:**
How I said initially, the question author needed to set another value for `root` and as I said in comment the right value is `/usr/src/app/symfony/public`

Comment: root directive must still be ./index.php and additional I would like to allow everything in ./styles and ./scripts and ./images

Comment: The style folder is normally available via HOSTNAME/styles/... because it is in [root]/public/styles,... Index file is [root]/public/index.php that works, so it seems I have to change this line: try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args; which seems to be blocking any other file than index.php

Comment: /index.php works because `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) ` block, and I noticed just now that  your path more complex ( `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/src/app/symfony/public/index.php`) so root value should be like this: `/usr/src/app/symfony/public/`

Comment: removing the index.php in "fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/src/app/symfony/public/index.php;" causes me into an error: File not found ...

Comment: Why are you removing "fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME ..."? You should not remove it, you need to change root in order to get your static files. Please, just try to change root and see what is happened.

Comment: I just removed the file part of it. Instead of "/usr/src/app/symfony/public/index.php;" I used "/usr/src/app/symfony/public;" But this caused me into "File not found"...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, just added those lines before the first location came

```
location /styles {
    root /usr/src/app/symfony/public/;
 }
```